# how to uncancel asynctask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have a method to populate images in a list view called fillimages which is an asynctask, my problem is if i want to refresh my app it waits untill fillimages finish then start the refresh which is a waste of time and resources, so inserted a cancel statment in side fillimages but the problem now when i refresh fillimages cancel and when i call it agian it will not run (because it reads the cancel part) can you help me with this, here is the code,

```
fillimages fl = new fillimages();
fl.excute();

public class fillimages extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        for(int i = 3;i<data.size();i++){

            if(fl.isCancelled()){
                Log.d("debug","fl canceled");
                break;

            }
            try {
                Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new URL(data.get(i).getImagelink()).openConnection().getInputStream());
                data.get(i).setBm(bm);

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AsyncTasks cannot be rerun once they have been cancelled; they are one-shot, so you have to create a new AsyncTask.

By the way, I would recommend that you use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) for setting images to ListView items.